# how to add a shake effect when i add an item to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have a purchase order that I want to improve
when I add an item to my cart, you see the item move to the cart

But I would like the "b-cart" class to be able to shake when I add an item

In addition, is it possible to increase the travel time of the image to the class "b-cart"

Thank you very much for the help I have been looking for a long time

I give you the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code

```js
var cart = $('.b-cart'),
  cartCountCont = cart.find('.b-cart__count'),
  cartCount = parseInt(cartCountCont.text(), 10),
  addToCart = $('.b-items__item__add-to-cart');

addToCart.on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();

  var el = $(this),
    item = el.parent(),
    img = item.find('.b-items__item__img'),
    cartTopOffset = cart.offset().top - item.offset().top,
    cartLeftOffset = cart.offset().left - item.offset().left;


  var flyingImg = $('<img class="b-flying-img">');
  flyingImg.attr('src', img.attr('src'));
  flyingImg.css('width', '200').css('height', '200');


  flyingImg.animate({
    top: cartTopOffset,
    left: cartLeftOffset,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    opacity: 0.1

  }, 800, function() {
    flyingImg.remove();
    cartCountCont.text(cartCount);
  });

  el.parent().append(flyingImg);
});
```

```css
.b-cart {
  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}

.b-items {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  .b-items__item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 12px 21px 12px;
    .b-items__item__img {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
        animation-duration: 4s;
      }
    }
  }
  .b-items__item__title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    color: #95A5A6;
  }
  .b-items__item__add-to-cart {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    display: block;
    background: #16A085;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 9px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0a9479;
  }
}

.b-flying-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  animation: fly 0.8s 1;
  -webkit-animation: fly 0.8s 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes fly {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Для Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Для IE */
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Для Opera */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Для Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Для IE */
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Для Opera */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fly {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-cart"></div>

<a style="cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 5px;data-url=" https://phil.pecheperle.be/image-perles/perle-verre-peche-gardon-2001.JPG " class="ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart "onclick="setTimeout(()=> ouvreMaJolieAlert(event), 1000);">
add to cart</a>
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the answer
here is a summary of my project
https://codepen.io/flexi2202/pen/eYrKOJR

Comment: I've converted the code from the question into a snippet which - once it's been edited to reproduce your problem, and to include jQuery (and presumably jQuery UI?) - can be run in the question itself to demonstrate the problem. In future, please take the time to post the code yourself and **do not** *just* post a demo on an external site (CodePen, JS Fiddle or anywhere else); they're useful, but they do not replace the need for the relevant code to be in your question.

Comment: Hello

I'm new so I didn't know what to do

Thanks for the correction and getting it in the correct form.